# Kendo UI Datasource Limitation

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui, datasource

I am having an issue with getting the values of an array within the kendo ui datasource object. I have searched and tried many things to fix, but have not found a solution in 3 weeks. Basically I want to get the values of an array named 'base64img' that is assigned as a field in the Kendo UI datasource, but I have been unable to get access to the data of the array value.
Here are all my stats:
(if there are errors in response, please ignore as I modified for security purposes)
XML Response -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <retrieveIncidentResponse xmlns="http://lal.lala.com/lala/messages/">
            <incidentStructure>
                <geoLoc>LALA1</geoLoc>
                <eventName>PARTY</eventName>
                <incidentStatus>OPEN</incidentStatus>
                <incidentCompltnDate>2012-01-02</incidentCompltnDate>
            </incidentStructure>
            <imageURI>IMAG0001.jpg</imageURI>
            <imageURI>IMAG0002.jpg</imageURI>
            <imageURI>IMAG0003.jpg</imageURI>
            <imageURI>IMAG0004.jpg</imageURI>
            <imageURI>IMAG0005.jpg</imageURI>
            <imageBase64>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD</imageBase64>
            <imageBase64>/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkM</imageBase64>
            <imageBase64>EQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJC</imageeBase64>
            <imageBase64>IeJBweHx7/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw4ICA4eFBEUHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eH</imageBase64>
```

Kendo DataSource Code:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(soapXMLResponse, "application/xml");
var dsIncPictures = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("ds error: " + e.status);
    },
    data: xmlDoc,
    schema: {
        type: "xml",
        data: "soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/retrieveIncidentResponse",
        model: {
            fields: {
                imageURI: "imageURI",
                imageBase64: "imageBase64"
            },
            hasChildren: true
        }
    },
    pageSize: 50
});

My attempts to get to the values:
/*$drt.globalEditIncWPics.fetch(function()
        {
            $drt.globalEditIncWPics._data(0).imageBase64(0).val;
            $drt.globalEditIncWPics.get("imageURI[0]");
            var field = $drt.globalEditIncWPics.get("imageURI[0]").imageURI[0].length;
            console.log($drt.globalEditIncWPics.get().imageURI(0));
            var field = $drt.globalEditIncWPics.at(0);
            console.log("VALUE: '" + field.text + "'");
            soapRequest.append(bind.soapRequestMessageFields(field.FieldName, field.value));
        });*/
        /*$drt.globalEditIncWPics.fetch();
        for (var idx = 0;idx<=$drt.globalEditIncWPics.length;idx++)
        {
            $drt.globalEditIncWPics.data[0].imageBase64[0].value;

        }*/
```

This is the results of the object Google developer tools:
Nevermind I was told that my reputation wasn't high enough to post picture.
pasting code from developer tool (nevermind it takes up too much space):
basically _prestineData has two arrays one called imageBase64 and imageURI in the 0|1 array spot and the values are shown as #text  in each child array spot (0,1,2,3, etc).

Comment: You'll be more likely to get a good answer if you can post a link to your code or create a jsFiddle sample. That said, I'm not sure how the XML you posted could be parsed automatically into the array structure you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at your source, here's a fetch function that seems to work, displaying all 4 values for `imageBase64`:

```
dsIncPictures.fetch(function() {
    var data = dsIncPictures.data();
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.length; rowIndex++) {
        var imageBase64 = data[rowIndex].imageBase64;
        for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < imageBase64.length; imageIndex++) {
            console.log(imageBase64[imageIndex]['#text']);
        }
    }
});
```

The full path to the first image of the first row is `data[0].imageBase64[0]['#text']`.

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch. It shows how much I really need to learn about pulling values from the DOM with JavaScript, etc. I have been banging my head against the wall on this forever and funny to see I was so close (in a way). Answer is correct. Thank you again.